# Validation errors - only for filled fields

Tags: reactjs, antd

The validation errors should be displayed if the fields to which they refer contain values, in the case a field does not contain any value, there should be no error message displayed.

If a user types something and then clears it, like empty values into the Input Field,
then it will not show any error message.

Here is the codesandbox links:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-chaum-lxxcml?file=/src/App.js

how can I do that now?

```
import React from "react";
import { Col, Form, Input } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form name="customValidationForm">
      <Col span={5}>
        <Form.Item
          name={"AIRCRAFT_ID"}
          label={"aircraft-id"}
          rules={[
            {
              pattern: /^[A-Z]{1}[A-Z0-9]{1,6}$/i,
              message: "Please enter a valid aircraft id",
              required: true,
            },
          ]}
          validateTrigger="onChange"
        >
          <Input maxLength={7} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `validator` function. You can read more about this [here](https://ant.design/components/form#rule), [here](https://ant.design/components/form#custom-validator-not-working) and [here](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-register).

Here's a simple example:

```
async function validateField( value ) {
  // if field is empty returns a resolved 
  // promise so this field will be ignored
  if ( !value || value.length <= 0 ) return Promise.resolve( true )

  const regex = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]{1}[A-Z0-9]{1,6}$/i)

  // if field is valid return a resolved promise
  if ( value.test( regex )) return Promise.resolve( true )

  // field is not valid and we should reject the promise
  return Promise.reject( new Error( "field not valid" ))
}

<Form.Item
  name={"Hello"}
  label={"Hello"}
  rules={[{
    pattern: /^[A-Z]{1}[A-Z0-9]{1,6}$/i,
    message: "Please enter a valid text",
    required: true,
    validator: (_, value) => validateField(value)
  }]}
  validateTrigger="onChange"
>
  <Input maxLength={7} />
</Form.Item>
```

OBS: validator function must be `async` and return `Promise`, otherwise it will not work.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-tree-kdpzpv?file=/src/App.js:69-386) is a working codesandbox example.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks,
// but I can't use this here,

```if ( !value || value.length <= 0 ) return Promise.resolve( true )```

// can we do that only the UI, not using the validation rules

Comment: I don't think that is possible to do this only with rules. In my tests I couldn't find any working way, only with validator